# .htaccess permanent redirect (301) problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the www and non-www version of my .fr url to a .com url.  the www works, but I can 't get the non-www working.  Any idea why the non-www Rewrite isn't working?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.fr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.fr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Complete .htaccess

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.44

RewriteEngine on
RewriteLogLevel 0
LogLevel debug 
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.domain\.fr|domain\.fr)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^nl/js/(.*)$ /js/$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/js/(.*)$ /js/$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^en/js/(.*)$ /js/$1 [L, NC]

RewriteRule ^nl/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L, NC]
```

And a bunch of rewrite rules like this

```
RewriteRule ^nl/news.asp$ n_news.asp [R]
RewriteRule ^fr/news.asp$ f_news.asp [R]
RewriteRule ^en/news.asp$ e_news.asp [R]
```

Comment: Do both of these domain.fr (www and non-www) are pointing into the same folder? **Sidenote:** you can combine them into a single rule, for example: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.domain\.fr|domain\.fr)$` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.fr$`

Comment: Tried both conditions, no luck.  The www version works, the non-www not.  Tried several things already, always works for the www, but not for the non-www...

Comment: I'll repeat my actual question, np: Do both of these domain.fr (www and non-www) are pointing into the same folder?

Comment: Sorry, they are indeed pointing to the same folder.

Comment: Can you post your whole htaccess then -- maybe you have some other rules that messing this somehow. Also ... try loose matching domain name, e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.fr [NC]` -- maybe it routed in some "interesting" way (like, for example, has port number as well etc)

Comment: I've edited my Q.  I hope this will give you enough info?  It's an old classic asp site on IIS.  Don't know if that makes a difference? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.fr [NC] doesn't make any difference.

Comment: As I understand (based on your htaccess) all what you want to do is to redirect **ANY** configured domain name to `www.domain.com`. In this case try this single rule instead of separate rule for each TLD (co.uk, .org, .eu etc) that you have: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]`. So anything that is not `www.domain.com` will be redirected to it.

Comment: OMG...  DNS was configured incorrectly. :-/ It works using your last RewriteCond, so thank you for your active help and short rule for the redirect.

Comment: Lets make it as an answer since it helped resolving the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand (based on your htaccess) all what you want to do is to redirect **ANY** configured domain name to `www.domain.com`.

In this case try this single rule instead of separate rule for each TLD (co.uk, .org, .eu etc) that you have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So anything that is not `www.domain.com` will be redirected to it.